# Using AFNetworking to update a UITableViewCell once a download is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

Within our app we have a free magazine that users can download in PDF format. If they have not downloaded an issue, that `UITableViewCell` image has a low alpha so that the user can see that it is not downloaded.

If you tap a cell it will start to download using an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and once complete you can view the PDF using `QuickLook`.

The problem I am having is, when the user initiates the download, then scrolls away and then back, the `UITableViewCell` that they tapped somehow loses reference that it was downloading and therefore doesn't update the `UIProgressView` or change the alpha to 1.0 when the download is finished. I cannot for the life of me figure out why `[[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]` is not equaling:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PUCViewpointItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Check to see if we are already on the row that is activated
    if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndexPath.row) {

        // File Path
        NSString *path = [self itemPath:item];

        // Should we read the issue
        if (item.isDownloaded && path) {
            item.downloadPath = path;
            [self readIssue:item];
            return;
        }

        // TableView Cell
        PUCViewpointTableViewCell *cell = (PUCViewpointTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!path) {

            Utility *utility = [[Utility alloc] init];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:item.url];
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            NSString *localPath = [[utility localDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.pdf", item.name];
            operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:localPath append:NO];
            [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

                float totalProgress = (float)totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead;
                if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
                    cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
                    cell.progressView.progress = totalProgress;
                    item.isDownloading = YES;
                    item.isDownloaded = NO;
                    item.progress = totalProgress;
                }

            }];
            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
                    cell.fullImage.alpha = 1.0f;
                    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
                    item.isDownloaded = YES;
                    item.isDownloading = NO;
                }
                NSLog(@"%d == %d", [tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row, indexPath.row);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
                    cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
                    item.isDownloading = NO;
                    item.isDownloaded = NO;
                }
            }];
            [operation start];

        }

        return;
    }

    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = self.selectedIndexPath;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    // Which way are we scrolling?
    UITableViewScrollPosition position;
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || (oldIndexPath && oldIndexPath.row < indexPath.row)) {
        position = UITableViewScrollPositionTop;
    } else {
        position = UITableViewScrollPositionBottom;
    }

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:position animated:YES];

}
```

If I start a download, then scroll down in my tableView, my `NSLog` statement will log something like `3 == 10` which makes no sense.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Which method is that? didSelectRowAtIndexPath? And where does the variable indexPath come from?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the question with the full method.

Comment: I don't even think you need this if: if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]). The block is already capturing the cell and the item.

Comment: TableViews recycle cells, so it's very possible that the cell that _was_ #3 has now been recycled and used in position #10, since you have scrolled #3 offscreen

Comment: Without the `if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath])` random cells get alpha of 1.0 and show the `UIProgressView` on the wrong cell. Trust me, I tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about your case so I wrote a little test project, you can find it here: https://github.com/mrojas/MRTableViewTest

Basically, the way to solve it was:

- Put the logic to download an item, in the item class
- Make the cell be the delegate of the item, to be notified about progress/completion
- When cells are scrolled (reused), setting the item on them is enough. They figure the current status and set themselves to be delegates.

Check the project, try it, and let me know if you have doubts.

I didn't use AFNetworking but instead simulated some task that takes 10 seconds to complete, in 2 seconds interval.

Comment: Brilliant! This delegate pattern makes much more sense in this situation. It totally worked and solved my issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: in which method we need to put logic of downloading

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to store somewhere (like an NSMutableArray instance variable) the indexPath you are downloading. so you can do something like that :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        if( [indexArray indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound )
        {
            // alpha for downloading
        }    
    }
```

In your AFNetworking completion blocks you should remove this indexPath from you indexArray.

As comments said, cells are not reliable for storing any kind of information as they are reallocated when you scroll

```
   @interface ViewController ()
    {
        NSMutableArray *_indexArray;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;
        _indexArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
        [self.view addSubview:table];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
    {
        return 50;
    }

// called when you scroll to new cells or when reloadData is called
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"default"];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        // red color if I'm downloading, else blue
        if ([_indexArray indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"cell in the table";
        return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        [_indexArray addObject:[indexPath copy]];
        NSLog(@"downloading...");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // update UI temporary (until scroll)

            // HD Image so I can scroll up and down for testing
        NSString *res = @"http://res.cloudinary.com/******/image/upload/*****/Motorola_Razr_HD_Cam_Sample_7_ftzrj0.jpg";
            // custom class for download
        [[PLSApi api] downloadDataAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:res] withBlock:^(NSData *data) {
            // download complete
            [_indexArray removeObject:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // update UI
            NSLog(@"finished...");
        }];
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a try. I wasn't storying anything in a cell, rather was storing it in a custom object within an `NSArray`.

Comment: Ok, a bit confused what you are saying to do here. I don't want to enable the alpha when they select the row. I want it after the download completes.

Comment: Ups updated the answer... miss copy paste :s I'm not sure that [indexArray indexOfObject:indexPath] is the right method here -I can't try right now- as I don't know how it compares IndexPath objects, but you can identify them with row and section attributes.

Comment: I will post some more detailled code tomorrow as it is 1am here, but the main issue is that any code you can do to your cell (UI/data) in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath is NOT reliable once you scrolled away - you have to handle it in cellForRowAtIndexPath